# Gifts of equity

Tags: taxes, real-estate, property-taxes

I am buying my brothers house for the remainder of the mortgage which is $60,000. The value house is valued at $125,000. Is there a tax or fine on the $65,000 of equity or can he gift it without any penalty?

Comment: All tax questions depend on the jurisdiction. Please specify the country.  Also specify if you or your brother are married.

Comment: Are you buying it or is it a gift ?